# PDFBOX, How to modify an existing font to make it bold or italic

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

My web application has a functionality to create PDF reports and it is implemented using iText 5. I have been tasked with migrating that implementation to PDFBox 2.0.27 but I'm stuck with everything font related.

iText5 provides the following method to create a non-embedded base font with a particular style like bold or italic:

```
baseFont = BaseFont.createFont(fontFilePath + style, BaseFont.WINANSI, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
```

I have been trying to replicate that using PDFBox but I can't seem to find a way to create a bold or italic font using the .ttf file of the original font. I have tried setting the font weight in the font dictionary, but it appears to have no effect

```
PDType0Font originalFont = PDType0Font.load(document,new File(fontFilePath));
COSDictionary dict = new COSDictionary(originalFont.getCOSObject());
dict.setInt(COSName.FONT_WEIGHT, 700);
dict.setItem(COSName.ENCODING, COSName.IDENTITY_H);
dict.setItem(COSName.FONT_FILE2, COSNull.NULL);
baseFont = new PDType0Font(dict);
```

I have also tried using the setFontWeight over the font descriptor of the base font, but again it has no effect

```
PDType0Font originalFont = PDType0Font.load(document,new File(fontFilePath));
COSDictionary dict = new COSDictionary(originalFont.getCOSObject());
dict.setItem(COSName.ENCODING, COSName.IDENTITY_H);
dict.setItem(COSName.FONT_FILE2, COSNull.NULL);
baseFont = new PDType0Font(dict);
baseFont.getFontDescriptor().setFontWeight(700);
```

Is there a way to do this without requiring another .ttf file representing the bold (or italic) version of the font?

Comment: No, and PDFBox always embeds except for the standard 14 fonts. Not embedding fonts is asking for trouble.

Comment: K J, could i bother you with futher explanation? I'm loading the font from a .ttf file provided by the user so it could be a vanilla font like "times roman" or not. I understand what you say about embedding but I sill can't figure out how to turn a PDType0Font into a bold one. Doing something like PDType0Font.load(document,new File(fontFilePath + style)) returns NullPointerException becasue I do not have a .ttf file for the bold variation of the font

Comment: You can't turn a loaded font into a bold font. You can simulate this somewhat, by using fill and stroke text rendering mode, but that isn't the real thing. You could also simulate italic by using a skew transformation, but that too isn't the real thing. I don't know itext, you should look at their javadoc to see what it does. "fontFilePath + style" wouldn't work anyway, you'd get "Times.ttfBold"